# GitHub Copilot Labs errors out when I ask it to explain code

Tags: github-copilot

I have both the GitHub Copilot and GitHub Copilot Labs extensions in VS Code. VS Code says I'm logged in to my github account. I signed up months ago for Copilot, and I believe I have the $10/month subscription running. I see regular Copilot suggestions in my PowerShell code as I type.

But when I select a line or a few of code, then click the cute little copilot icon on the left, then click "Explain code", I always get the following error:

> Error generating Copilot response, please try again. Changes in the prompt or stop sequence might fix this. If this error happens repeatedly check that you are logged into GitHub and have access to both Copilot and Copilot Labs.

I looked at https://docs.github.com/en/copilot/troubleshooting-github-copilot/troubleshooting-common-issues-with-github-copilot , but it doesn't seem to describe my situation.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What programming language are you using? Copilot only support a limited set of programming languages and file types, check here: https://docs.github.com/en/copilot/getting-started-with-github-copilot.

You also can try clearing the cache of VSCode and restart the environment.

Or you can try **Visual Studio Code Insiders** https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/ with the GitHub Copilot extension.

Comment: I work with PowerShell. It works fine in Copilot when I'm typing in an edit window, making good suggestions.

Comment: It's just when I click "Ask Copilot" under 'Github Copilot Labs' that it balks.

I have tried it in 'Visual Studio Code - Insiders', too. Same results.

I just cleared the cache, and that also didn't help.

Any other ideas?

Comment: I checked, my github account shows my Copilot subscription (I can't show the screenshot, so this cut-n-paste probably won't look like much):  
Add-ons
GitHub Copilot
Your AI powered pair programmer
Yearly plan
$100.00